# Parse JSON in JQuery and set in inputs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I'm implementing a web and I need to use AJAX+JQuery to complete some fields without recharging the page. I test it and it works correctly but when I tried to use a real JSON (created by MySQL) I'm not be able to parse it.

The format of JSON is this:

```
[  
   {  
      "ID":"5847"
   },
   {  
      "Usuari":"admin"
   },
   {  
      "Nom":"admin"
   },
   {  
      "Cognom1":null
   },
   {  
      "Cognom2":null
   },
   {  
      "Tipus":"admin"
   },
   {  
      "Progres":"0"
   }
]
```

And the AJAX code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#botoBuscar").click(function(){
                $.ajax({url: "http://192.168.1.39/web/api/buscarUser.php?user="+ $("#userInput").val(), success: function(data){
                   var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                    $("#id").val(obj[0]['ID']);
                    $("#user").val(obj[0]['Usuari']);
                    $("#nom").val(obj[0]['Nom']);
                    $("#cognom1").val(obj[0]['Cognom1']);
                    $("#cognom2").val(obj[0]['Cognom2']);
                    $("#tipus").val(obj[0]['Tipus']); 
                    $("#progres").val(obj[0]['Progres']);                  
                }});
            });
        });
```

If I print only the var "data", it prints correctly the full JSON, but if I try to use data['ID'] or data[0]['ID'], etc.. it doesn't print anything. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

If you need, the code to generate JSON is this (PHP):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, user, nom, cognom1, cognom2, tipus, progres  FROM users WHERE user='".$_GET['user']."'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$id = $row['id'];
$user = $row['user'];
$nom = $row['nom'];
$c1 = $row['cognom1'];
$c2 = $row['cognom2'];
$tipus = $row['tipus'];
$progres = $row['progres'];

//build the JSON array for return
$json = array(array('ID' => $id),
                array('Usuari' => $user),
                array('Nom' => $nom),
                array('Cognom1' => $c1),
                array('Cognom2' => $c2),
                array('Tipus' => $tipus),
                array('Progres' => $progres));
echo json_encode($json);

mysqli_close($db);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to get the values correctly. The code is the following one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#botoBuscar").click(function(){
                $.ajax({url: "http://XX.com/api/buscarUser.php?user="+ $("#userInput").val(), success: function(data){
                   var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                    $("#id").val(obj[0]['ID']);
                    $("#user").val(obj[1]['Usuari']);
                    $("#nom").val(obj[2]['Nom']);
                    $("#cognom1").val(obj[3]['Cognom1']);
                    $("#cognom2").val(obj[4]['Cognom2']);
                    $("#tipus").val(obj[5]['Tipus']); 
                    $("#progres").val(obj[6]['Progres']);                  
                }});
            });
        });
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the best way to solve it, but it works :)
If someone knows a better solution just post and I'll mark it as a best answer. If in two days I don't get any answer I'll mark my own answer as correct. Thanks!